# How to grab a whole body unless header and footer of another site page

Tags: java, liferay, webgrabber

I'm developing with ***Liferay portal***.
And now I'm facing a little **problem**:

I'm making site for some Company that has subsidiaries.
**Then**, I must cut out some parts(precisely header and footer)
of other site(sub. site) and put the body of page without'em in **iframe** of main site.

I was *"googling"*, looking for something about **Grabbers**.
**but** I've found just about how to grab with PHP or Perl. 
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382134/how-to-grab-content-from-another-website)
It doesn't seem to be exact what I need.

Comment: I found [jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/), now trying to make something, if anybody has other suggestions, please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the WebProxy portlet for this.

As you'll have to modify the external content's body, you can't simply show it in an iframe, so this portlet might be what you need. It doesn't work with an iframe internally and you can replace some content on-the-fly.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried it, but I still can't cut out "head" and "foot" of the page. I need just "middle" of the body.